# How to show multiple annotation details at single point?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

I am working in xamarin ios. I am using MKMapView to show some locations. I have some tasks and there locations(latitude, longitude). I have mapped the locations on Map and when user click on annotation point it shows task's description.

But in some cases multiple tasks can have same locations, so in that case task descriptions shows one by one when user click at annotation point. But I want that when user click on annotation point all the task description for that point should show together like a list. How it is possible in xamarin ios?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom annotation view to display all the tasks' descriptions of the point:

```
public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation (MKMapView mapView, NSObject annotation)
{    
        if (annotation is MKUserLocation){
            return null; 
        }

        //Use a custom annotationView instead, which inherited from MKAnnotationView, has a label to display description.
        ACustomMKAnnotationView annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation (annotationId);

        if (annotationView == null) {
            annotationView = new ACustomMKAnnotationView (annotation, annotationId);
        }

        annotationView.descriptionLabel.text = "All the task description joined";
        annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

        return annotationView;
}
```

Take a reference from: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/ios_maps_walkthrough/